How to configure VPN on Debian Linux Network Manager to use it with Built-In Windows client?
My goal is just to have Linux-based VPN server to which I could connect with build-in Windows client without installing third-party client software on Windows (security requirements not to use third-party software on client computers).
I am looking at the NetworkManager, but I am not sure that it provides the solution expect using openVPN which is not the case with my requirements above.
Is there a chance to configure NetworkManager to get Linux server working with Windows Built-In VPN client? If so, how this could be achieved?
If this is not the best way, what is the recommended approach for a newcomer in Linux/Network/VPN to setup a VPN server easy and fast to get it working with Windows Built-In VPN client?


Is there a chance to configure NetworkManager to get Linux server working with Windows Built-In VPN client? If so, how this could be achieved?

No, NetworkManager and its plugins only support setting up VPN clients (or equal peers in case of wireguard, but Windows doesn't support that), not VPN servers.

Thank you. Can you, please pinpoint the source? Don't get me wrong, I want to make sure before I finally give up with it.

How should I source "It doesn't exist"? That's impossible, logically. It just doesn't exist. You can look, and the option is not there – you don't need a source for that. Other than that, hi! I guess this post now is an original source you could cite on Wikipedia.

Sounds fair. I mostly meant some kind of documentation on the product which states this explicitly or makes this obvious from the list of the supported protocols, etc. Something that makes you sure that you didn't miss some part which makes it.

I don't really agree with the "Product" wording there, nobody is selling NetworkManager to you.

Well, I am not a native speaker, but the dictionary along with other meanings say: (1) "a thing or person that is the result of an action or process" and (2)"something produced". So, in is not required to be connected with selling. Anyway, can we get back to the point through the thorny wording? Is there something that could be used in the specs to make sure that NetworkManager isn't suitable to do this?

It's not "not suitable"; it simply "doesn't do". You can install NetworkManager just as well as I can, and then ask it to list the kind of connections it can make. If you see no "VPN server" in there, well, that's your primary source. It doesn't get any more primary source than that. You don't need anyone else to do that.
